# Notification not showing up time in android

Tags: android

I have created custom notification, I am not able to show current time in my notification bar.. It is not coming even though I am showing `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

```
final Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.notificationicon, context.getResources().getString(R.string.notificationheadingtext), System.currentTimeMillis());
            notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
            notification.when = System.currentTimeMillis();
            int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
            if (currentapiVersion > 20)
            {
                notification.contentView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_process);    
            }
            else
            {
                notification.contentView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_process_lowerversion);
            }

            Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            notification.sound = alarmSound;
            notification.contentIntent = pendingIntent;
            notification.contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.status_icon, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            notification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.status_text, context.getResources().getString(R.string.notificationheadingtext));

            notificationManager.notify(42, notification);
```

Answer (score 0):

Notification class is deprecated. Use [NotificationCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html). Read this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)